# How to order by a specific order using a field determined by a case statement

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have the following query (simplified version for the question)

```
select case when pool_type in ('WN','PL','SH','EX','QN') 
  then pool_type else 'Other' end as pooltype,
sum(wagered)
from wageringactivitytable
group by case when pool_type in ('WN','PL','SH','EX','QN') 
then pool_type else 'Other' end
```

I wish to order the results in a specific order (WN,PL,SH,EX,QN,Other)  Is this even possible given the way I've constructed my sql query?

I tried using another case statement (with numbers such as 'case pool_type when 'WN' then 1  when 'PL' then 2 etc..) but that won't work because pool_type is not valid in the order by clause because it is neither contained in an agregate function or a group by clause....

I tried refering to the column position rather than it's name, but in this case the order is completely ignored..

```
case 1 when 'WN' then 1
when 'PL'then 2
....

when 'Other' then 6

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with an outer query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select case when pool_type in ('WN','PL','SH','EX','QN') 
      then pool_type else 'Other' end as pooltype,
    sum(wagered)
    from wageringactivitytable
    group by case when pool_type in ('WN','PL','SH','EX','QN') 
    then pool_type else 'Other' end
) T
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN pooltype = 'WN' THEN 1 
       WHEN ...
  END
```

Another way to do this is make a helper table... eg

```
pooltypeorderer
pooltype poolorder
WN       1
PL       2
etc
```

Then you join to that table and group by both pool_type and pool_order

I like this second option because it is easy to maintain, you can change the order (or add new types) without changing your code.  It does make the query look a little more complex (since it has an extra join).

Comment: I thought about this option.   I may end up doing this (in which case I'll accept your answer)

Comment: @MrVimes - see option 2!  :D

Comment: Thanks. I did have a look at option 2.  I went with option 1 for my immediate purposes, but I will consider changing to option 2 for ease of maintenance